# View duplicate record in a row in Grid

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

This Query Return Several Record  And I Show Result In a Grid
I want Show All Record in a Record With Multi Column

```
select  Acceptor.Terminal, Acceptor.AcceptorName 
            ,Em.CauseDamage, Em.DescriptionDamage                                        
            from Em  
            left outer join Acceptor on Acceptor.Terminal = Em.Terminal 
            where     (Acceptor.Terminal = '70460440')



Terminal  AcceptorName CauseDamage   DescriptionDamage
-------------------------------------------------------
70460440  Alvin        reason1       Comments1
70460440  Alvin        reason2       Comments2
70460440  Alvin        reason3       Comments3
```

I Want Show Result In grid

```
Terminal  AcceptorName  CauseDamage1   DescriptionDamage1 CauseDamage2  DescriptionDamage2  CauseDamage3   DescriptionDamage3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
70460440  Alvin         reason1       Comments1           reason2       Comments2           reason3        Comments3
```

Comment: Count Records Are not Fixed

Comment: Then you left out a critical detail in your question.  You should Google "dynamic pivot query SQL Server" for more information.

Comment: Have you tried something yourself yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

this query is just going to let you start work and will guide you to final results if you got it. **this is not a final result end query** so you can try this and it will guide you to use of PIVOT in your case and it is for dynamic columns for fixed. so you can just modify it as per your requirements;

```
select * from Tempt
go
select * from  tempt2
go
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumnname AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns_cd AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
--Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT   @PivotColumnname= COALESCE(@PivotColumnname + ',','') +
QUOTENAME(name)
FROM (select name from Tempt where towncd = '0001') AS PivotExample
SELECT   @PivotColumns_cd = COALESCE(@PivotColumns_cd + ',','') + 
QUOTENAME(second_col)
FROM (select second_col from Tempt where towncd = '0001') AS PivotExample_a
--Create the dynamic query with all the values for
--pivot column at runtime
print(@PivotColumnname)
print(@PivotColumns_cd)
SET   @SQLQuery =
 '( SELECT name2,towncd,' +   @PivotColumnname + ',' +   @PivotColumns_cd +'
   FROM (select  tempt2.name2, tempt2.towncd ,Tempt.name, Tempt.second_col
    from Tempt  left outer join tempt2 on tempt2.towncd = Tempt.towncd 
    where tempt2.towncd = ''0001'')x
    PIVOT( max(name) FOR name IN (' + @PivotColumnname+')) 
    AS p1
    PIVOT( max(second_col) FOR second_col IN (' + @PivotColumns_cd+')) AS 
P)'execute(@SQLQuery)
```

here i created two table to match your scenario and put test data inside.
Tempt:

```
seqno   name    towncd  Counttown_cd    second_col
---------------------------------------------------
1       usman   0001    1               dam1
3       test    0003    NULL            NULL
1       usman2  0001    2               dam2
2       usman3  0001    3               dam3
```

tempt2:

```
 id towncd  name2
------------------
1   0001    man
2   0003    test
```

this query will result like below:

```
 name2  towncd  usman   usman2  usman3  dam1    dam2    dam3
-------------------------------------------------------------
man     0001    NULL    NULL    usman3  NULL    NULL    dam3
man     0001    NULL    usman2  NULL    NULL    dam2    NULL
man     0001    usman   NULL    NULL    dam1    NULL    NULL
```